# How to redirect user when he clicks on home button?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

Can you help me to get the following steps :

1. When user click on the button Home:
2. It display a screen that contains a message `Action not allowed`.
3. This screen is displayed for a few seconds.
4. Then User will be redirected to `MainActivity`.

I work with `4.1.1` Android version so I can't override Home button.

Comment: Have your tried anything?

Comment: Implement your own home screen. There is no other supported means for you to intercept the HOME button.

Comment: It's not duplicated because therse in any solution for version higher than 2.3 @Manu

Answer (score 0):

Use a new activity which contains your Action not allowed message, redirect the user to is. Then, in it, you can set a `Timer`  with your waiting time and redirect the user to MainActivity. Check out android doc about timer here : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: Thanks for help @Rogue but my problem is  how to redirect when click on Home button not with timer

Comment: Oh, didn't see it that way. You can't catch input on home button, refer to this answer for further details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972166/how-to-listener-homebutton-in-android

Comment: Yes, it not works because you can't catch click on home button.

Comment: But I know several app with home button disabled like Kids Place application for example