# android notify when user press home button more than once to start app

Tags: android

can the android system fire an event if the home button is pressed more than once ? 
I want to catch this action in order to play a alert message or music if the user presses the home button more than once.

Can we keep count of home button press in a day ?

when my app is running in background it should play music when user presses home button twice.
is it possible? and how to achieve this ?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.startv.gumrah

i want to implement functionality used in this app.

Thanks :)

Comment: Nope. You can not detect Home key press events... Home key is left for User Security and we can't hack it...

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.startv.gumrah  how to implement functionality of this app.

Comment: "Home key" is not the same as "Power button"

Comment: Exactly what I am going to say...]

Comment: thank you but how to detect power button if pressed twice to start music service ?? any code sample will help alot :)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940922/activate-an-application-when-a-power-button-is-clicked and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907102/home-button-listener

Answer (score 0):

please refer the link:- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_HOME

Key code constant: Home key. This key is handled by the framework and is never delivered to applications.